# using exit in my custom wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, header

To one of the user, on clicking the save settings button of a plugin, user is redirected only with the message "your license has been activated" with a white screen

I know this question have been answered many a times before. I tried many solutions such as removing blank space if any, adding ob_start() inside the function but it's not resolved yet

[image: Message getting displayed on white screen]

Line 360 in my code

```
<p><?php _e('Your license has been activated!', $lang_slug);?></p>
```

Pluggable.php code

```
function wp_redirect($location, $status = 302) {
global $is_IIS;

/**
 * Filters the redirect location.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 *
 * @param string $location The path to redirect to.
 * @param int    $status   Status code to use.
 */
$location = apply_filters( 'wp_redirect', $location, $status );

/**
 * Filters the redirect status code.
 *
 * @since 2.3.0
 *
 * @param int    $status   Status code to use.
 * @param string $location The path to redirect to.
 */
$status = apply_filters( 'wp_redirect_status', $status, $location );

if ( ! $location )
    return false;

$location = wp_sanitize_redirect($location);

if ( !$is_IIS && PHP_SAPI != 'cgi-fcgi' )
    status_header($status); // This causes problems on IIS and some FastCGI setups

header("Location: $location", true, $status); //line no: 1195

return true;
}
endif;
```

PHP function in custom plugin

```
public static function notice_valid_license() {
?>
<div class="updated">
    <p><?php _e('Your license has been activated!',$lang_slug);?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Should I add **exit;** before the end of the function?

Please can anyone suggest me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is causing that redirect - is it your plugin itself?

Comment: @CBroe Yes a plugin itself

Comment: You can not show output to the user and do an HTTP redirect at the same time.

Comment: How can I resolve this? Also to add a note, it happens only with few users

Comment: Decide whether you want to output a message, _or_ redirect elsewhere.

Comment: Actually redirection should happen but it is showing this message unexpectedly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146161/discussion-between-himani-and-cbroe).

Comment: Maybe not the issue, but if I remember correctly, you should not use vars for language: `$lang_slug`, it has to be the raw string